# Why is のだった used here?

Tags: explanatory-の

> 士道とのデートはとても楽しい。二人で歩いているだけで、喋っているだけで、本当に時間を忘れてしまうような感覚を得ることができる。 でも、いや、だからこそ---------士道がいなくなってしまったあとの寂しさは、より強くなってしまう**のだった**。

Hi. I know のだった has some different usages than のだ. For example, according to 大辞林,

> （「のだった」の形で）事態の説明をやや詠嘆的に言い表す。 「一人思い出にふける－・だった」

Does the above definition apply to my example? If not, is the のだった in my example just past tense of のだ? If so, is there any reason why のだった is used there instead of simply のだ?
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

That definition is fine, but you can just consider it as a cliche in narratives.